# Android - connectionState callback missing for ASP.NET Core SignalR for Android?

Tags: android, callback, rx-java, asp.net-core-signalr

I have the following connection code -

```kotlin
 private val authorization = App.context?.getSharedPreferences(authorizationPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.getString(authorizationToken, defaultStringValue)
    var hubConnection: HubConnection? = null

    fun startConnection() {
        if (hubConnection != null) return
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create(Constants.twoverteBaseUrl.plus(SignalREndpoints.accessSecureChatQuery))
            .withHeader("Authorization", authorization).build().apply { start() }
    }
```

I am missing the open to know exactly when connection is connected as it takes a few milisec and if I put my code after that `start()` I will get connectionState as `DISCONNECTED` because it did not have the time to connect yet.

I am sure there is a callback for this one.

How do I put the connectionState callback here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hubConnection.start() returns an [RxJava Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Completable.html), so if you want to do things once the connection has started, you need to subscribe to the Completable and run some code when it completes.

Example:

```java
hubConnection.start().subscribe(() -> {
// connected
},
error -> {
// error
});
```

Comment: just tried that and I couldn't get it. can you please type it according to my example?

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but it should be something like
```java
fun startConnection() {
    if (hubConnection != null) return
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create(Constants.twoverteBaseUrl.plus(SignalREndpoints.accessSecureChatQuery))
        .withHeader("Authorization", authorization).build().apply { start().subscribe(() -> {
            // connected
        },
        error -> {
            // error
        });}
}
```